# Is there any way in C++ to cast/copy a Parent class into a Child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I receive a complicated object from a framework I can't really change:

```
Parent parent = framework.get();
```

I would like to add some attributes and methods to this parent:

```
class Child : public Parent {
    public:
        inline Child() {}
        int extraVariable = 999;
        int extraMethod() { return 666; }
    };
```

Is there any way to 'cast' or copy an instantiated Parent into a Child class, other than manually copying all the attributes?

The python equivalent would be

```
class Child(Parent):
    def extraMethod(self):
        return 666

parent = framework.get()
parent.__class__ = Child
```

I realize C++ isn't python but I'm willing to hack it together (this is personal code, i.e. ugly is fine).

Comment: How do you know that `framework.get()` is returning a `Child`?  It could return anything derived from `Parent`.  Your best bet is `dynamic_cast`, even though that is a code smell using it.

Comment: Why inherit?, `struct Wrapper { Parent parent; int extraVariable; /*...*/};`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Given that the function returns a *value* (assuming `Parent` is indeed a class and not a typedef) we *know* that it doesn’t return a `Child`.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this? Knowing this will help us provide useful solutions.

Comment: This is the drawbacks of trying to do line-by-line translations from one language to C++.  You shouldn't need to hack anything together -- understand what that framework is doing, and then use proper C++ idioms to replicate the framework.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `framework.get()` returns a `Parent`, the `Child` class is my own invention. @Jarod42 , the inheritance would be nice because I can reuse some other code. But yes, I suppose this would work as well.

Comment: You could add a `Child` constructor that makes use of `Parent`s copy constructor (if it has one): 
`Child(const Parent& p) :
        Parent(p),
        extraVariable{999}
    {}`

Comment: @KonradRudolph , the `framework` I use stores C++ instances to a file which can later be read in python. I am trying to store some extra information in the C++ class before dumping it to a file.

Comment: @ComboCosmo unless `Parent` is specifically designed to support that (using `virtual` methods for streaming, etc) then you can't just arbitrarily add new data fields to `Parent` and expect the framework to know what to do with them. How do you expect the framework to know what a `Child` is if it is defined in your own code? How are you planning on "dumping it [a Child] to a file" exactly?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't control the `framework` source code I get my objects from, and the source code isn't well suited for what I am trying to do. I think that is in general where 'hacky' questions come from - a user must deal with code A but wants to do thing B that A wasn't intended for.

Comment: @ComboCosmo that is not how C++ works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I have properly registered the `Child` in the `framework`, all that works. The problem is converting the information stored in a `Parent` to the same information stored in a `Child`.

Comment: @ComboCosmo you can't magically turn a `Parent` object into a `Child` if it was not created as a `Child` to begin with.  All you can do instead is create a new `Child` object and copy the previous `Parent` data into the `Child`'s inherited `Parent` fields as needed, such as with a copy constructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay then I guess that answers the question in the title with "No". I will make a specific constructor that just copies all public and privates attributes then. Little disappointed that C++ can't even be ugly-hacked to do this.

Comment: If you go that route, why not reuse the `Parent` copy constructor as I suggested above so you don't need to copy each member variable by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a converting constructor, or two, to `Child`.

Example:

```
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    // converting constructors
    Child(const Parent& p) : Parent(p) {}        // copy
    Child(Parent&& p) : Parent(std::move(p)) {}  // move

    //...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rqZdHk)

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was searching for, works splendidly! Thanks!